# Vector and Layer Data Structure

Tags: computer-science, data-layers

I'm working with some code that is confusing me and I'm wondering if I'm just not grokking the data structures. The data I'm working with utilizes vectors and layers. I believe a vector is just a row of data but I'm not sure.

Any information you could provide or point me to about the use of these would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest view of a vector is a fixed-size list, such as a one-dimensional array.

I've never heard of a "Layer", and googling turned up nothing relevant either.

What are you trying to do?